# SQL - Return most recent row from history table

Tags: sql

I am working with Salesforce Lead and Contact data ('people') and parsing the record ownership history to see if a certain type of user currently owns or previously owned one of these people.

There are instances where one person or multiple people may have owned a record, in which case I want to return the more recent owner info (based on assignment date)

Here is my SQL, which returns duplicate rows for each Lead/Contact record.

```
with history as (
  select 
    id, 
    leadid as lead_or_contact_id, 
    createddate, 
    field, 
    oldvalue, 
    newvalue 
    from salesforce_leadhistory
  union
  select
    id, 
    contactid as lead_or_contact_id, 
    createddate,
    field, 
    oldvalue, 
    newvalue
  from salesforce_contacthistory
)

select 
  h.createddate as assignment_date,
  h.lead_or_contact_id,
  coalesce(old_user.name, new_user.name) as user_name,
  coalesce(old_user.id, new_user.id) as user_id,
  coalesce(old_user_role.name, new_user_role.name) as user_role
from history h
left join salesforce_user new_user on new_user.id = h.newvalue
left join salesforce_userrole new_user_role on new_user_role.id = new_user.userroleid
left join salesforce_user old_user on old_user.id = h.oldvalue
left join salesforce_userrole old_user_role on old_user_role.id = old_user.userroleid
where 
  field = 'Owner'
  and ( old_user_role.name like 'SDR%' or new_user_role.name like 'SDR%' )
```

This returns, for example, two rows that refer to the same person record:

```
assignment_date                 lead_or_contact_id  user_name        user_id    user_role
2020-01-01T00:42:37.000+00:00   00QXYZ              Joe Jones   123        SDR - EMEA
2020-10-14T03:25:39.000+00:00   00QXYZ              Max Clark   456        SDR - USA
```

In this instance, I would prefer all of the data from the second row (assignment date of 2020-10-14, user_name of Max Clark, user_id 456, and user_role "SDR - USA" to be returned since that is the most recent assignment history.

How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `row_number()`

```
select * from
(
select 
  h.createddate as assignment_date,
  h.lead_or_contact_id,
  coalesce(old_user.name, new_user.name) as user_name,
  coalesce(old_user.id, new_user.id) as user_id,
  coalesce(old_user_role.name, new_user_role.name) as user_role,row_number() over(partition by h.lead_or_contact_id order by h.createddate desc) as rn
from history h
left join salesforce_user new_user on new_user.id = h.newvalue
left join salesforce_userrole new_user_role on new_user_role.id = new_user.userroleid
left join salesforce_user old_user on old_user.id = h.oldvalue
left join salesforce_userrole old_user_role on old_user_role.id = old_user.userroleid
where 
  field = 'Owner'
  and ( old_user_role.name like 'SDR%' or new_user_role.name like 'SDR%' )
)A where rn=1
```